# People "editing" post without actually changing anything

Tags: discussion, editing

The other day, a saw a user edit 27 post, in like 30 min, and it seems (haven't checked them all, but a couple of them confirmed this); Also today, he did this to one of my posts.

It seems hes just farming reputation, which I don't think is allowed.

So, what can I do people "editing" post without actually changing anything?

Answer (score 5):

Yes that was me (I think). I can assure you that I am not reputation farming, or just editing every question for no reason.
I do a lot of retags, editing questions just to keep the tags clean. So it can look like I'm not editing the question, and in some cases I'm not changing any of the text in the question, just the tags.

About getting reputation:
Any user with over 1000 reputation does not get any reputation for editing questions. If a user has less then 1000 reputation then (as [gandal3](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/439/2217) mentioned) the edits go through a review process, and if they are useless then they would not be approved.

If you see some suspicious edits, ask a question in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm), or here on the meta.

Answer (score 2):

If the user is getting reputation, the edits would go through the review process and would be rejected if they are invalid.

I think the user in question is @David, who has the [privilege](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to edit questions and answers without going through the review queue and won't gain rep from editing.

We [discussed earlier](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16834246#16834246) in the chat about clarifying and separating the [baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking) and [texture-baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-baking) tags, so presumably this is what that was about.

Comment: Indee, but he didn't change anything, in most posts...

Comment: @someonewithpc I don't think you can save your edits if you don't edit anything. I think if you check the history you'll find they are all tag edits

Comment: Ok. But isn't this site for this kind of things? Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @someonewithpc Which site? The main site? or meta? This is a fine meta question if that's what your asking..

Comment: @gandal3 Yes, the meta.

Comment: @someonewithpc See http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta for an overview.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated; BTW when it says bugs, is it bugs with the website, or with Blender itself(assuming it's the former).

Comment: Bugs with the website. Blender bugs should go on the [tracker](https://developer.blender.org).

Comment: I knew about the tracker, but should I discuss the bugs here first, to see if they are indeed bugs and if more people are getting them, or should I post them directly in the tracker?

Comment: @someonewithpc I thought of that too, see  http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2389/599. If it's not a bug, the worst that can happen is that the report will be closed.