# Tag cleaning discussions

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

How should we discuss and decide the scopes, synonyms, need for, lack of need, etc. of tags?

We have been discussing this mainly on the chat with whichever frequent users happen to be around, but would this be better done on meta?

This way old discussions would be easier to find for reference purposes, and current discussions are more likely to be seen by other users who may want to put a word in.

If we do decide to keep tag discussions to meta, should we have one big post which gets continually updated? Or separate posts for each discussion/tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should be very careful when making a precedent for all future tag changes.

There have been lost of questions on the meta about tag changes, that have had no real consensus, and have gone nowhere. [version tags](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-should-be-the-version-tags), [snapping tag](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/snapping-tag-and-general-tag-organization), [baking tag](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/usage-of-baking-tag) (which has sense been dealt with and questioned [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/438/people-editing-post-without-actually-changing-anything))

I agree that a major tag changes, are better documented on the meta. However when I or others propose a tag change in the chat, it is talked about and dealt with right away. I'm hesitant to open up future tag discussions to such indecision as the old tag discussions have had here on the meta.

If the overall consensus is to move to the meta, I would suggest separate questions for each tag's major change. One massive question being edited and updated, is no better then having the discussion in the chat.

Comment: I agree with this. The community should get a say in any significant changes that occur, so anything relevant regarding tag changes proposed or discussed in chat should have an accompanying post here.

Comment: So just to be clear, as I understand it, the general idea is to discuss tag changes in chat, and then put a post on meta if it's a largish change?

Comment: @gandalf3 what you wrote sounds good to me.